# Powershell keep looping until condition is true then proceed

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that so far is able to check a file "latest.json" for the "created_at" object which shows the last date that a commit has occurred for software.

```
 $websiteJson = Invoke-WebRequest "https://website/latest.json" | ConvertFrom-Json  | select created_at

$todaysDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" 

if($websitejson.created_at | where {$_.created_at -eq $todaysDate}){
Write-Output "Today's date matches"

} else {
    Write-Output "has not yet been updated"
}
```

How part of latest.json  looks like

```
"created_at":"2020-03-23 17:32:48"
```

How do I change this to keep looping until the date pull from latest.json matches then proceed to next step (would download and install software).  **Also, since "created at" has "17:32:48" will this cause the date check to fail since the time does not match?**

. I want it to keep checking if dates match.

Thank you!

Comment: how often is the info updated?

Comment: Window is 4 hours, and can come out at any point during that 4 hours.

Comment: so you wold want to check at what interval? 0400, 0800, 1200, etc. seem fine for the primary interval ... then perhaps 5 minutes for a secondary interval?

Comment: Would be every minute.  Task scheduler would call ps1 at start of window and then run until updates comes out then once update hits loop condition is met and will proceed to update.

Comment: your JSON will be in a powershell object. so that means you can convert the _date string_ to a _date object_ and compare the date part. the standard date object has a `.Date` property that will give you the date part with the time part set to zero. do that to both and you can compare the date part cleanly.

Comment: Was thinking of doing the following: created_at.Substring(0,10) to return just the date not minutes from json. and then change Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: the problem with that is comparing DATE STRINGS instead of DATE OBJECTS. i would convert your JSON info to a `[datetime]` object and then use `.Date` on it to get just hte date part.

Comment: Any example of how to do so?

Comment: i added and Answer that shows using datetime objects & converting from a date _string_ to a date  _object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I'm not going to bother converting dates to match to make sure they're the same format, but what you need for your specific questions is just a `do until` loop. I might update this to check the date formats if you supply an example layout of the returned JSON.

```
Do{
    $websiteJson = Invoke-WebRequest "https://website/latest.json" | ConvertFrom-Json  | select created_at
    $todaysDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" 

    if($websitejson.created_at | where {$_.created_at -eq $todaysDate}){
        Write-Output "Today's date matches"

    } else {
        Write-Output "has not yet been updated"
    }

    start-sleep -s 60

}until($websiteJson -eq $todaysDate)
```

I believe this wont work right off the bat. You'll have to get the JSON date and $todaysDate to be the same format, then you can do this and it will work.

Comment: Was thinking of doing the following: created_at.Substring(0,10) to return just the date not minutes from json. and then change Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare the date and/or time, use *datetime objects* instead of *datetime strings*. something like this ...

if you want to test for the actual time difference between two time objects ...

```
((Get-Date -Date '2020-03-23 18:11:22') - [datetime]'2020-03-23 17:32:48').TotalHours
# result = 0.642777777777778
```

you keep mentioning *date* as if you don't want the time, so this method would work for comparing the date parts of two timestamps ...

```
# the date at the time the code was run = 2020 April 03, Friday 4:30:34 PM
$Today = (Get-Date).Date
$Created_At = '2020-04-03 15:15:15'

$Today -eq ([datetime]$Created_At).Date
```

result = `True`